# Xamarin custom BindableProperty with Converter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, bindable

I have a custom View with a custom BindableProperty:

```
public string Valore {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValoreProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValoreProperty, value); }
        }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ValoreProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Valore),
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(VolosTimePickerView),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: ValorePropertyChanged,
            propertyChanging: ValorePropertyChanging
        );
```

In my XAML, since the value of `Valore` is a nullable `Int`, I must use a converter like this:

```
<view:VolosTimePickerView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
     Valore="{Binding OrariSelezionati.ViaggioInizioMattina, Converter={StaticResource NullableConverter}}" />
```

How can I do the same thing, without using `Converter={StaticResource NullableConverter` in XAML side, but in code behind directly on the property?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `BindableProperty` ? Why can't it be a regular Property which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged ` ?

Comment: Why do you need to set a converter in your code-behind? Have you considered to expose a Nullable-Int BindableProperty and then in the ValorePropertyChanged event handler update the value of a regular String Property? In this case you don't need of a converter and the logic is implemented inside the ContentView.
Instead if you really really want to set converter from code-behind try to take a look here
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18849/how-do-i-use-ivalueconverters

Answer (score 0):

Your `Valore` is a `string`. Try to convert it into `Nullable<int> Valore`. See what happens.

And try to bind the value of the Valore inside your `ViewModel` also. So you would get

```
Nullable<int> _Valore;
public Nullable<int> Valore {get; set;}
```